# How can I execute some code before a page was loaded?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am new to Chrome extension development. I'm going to make an extension that will do nothing but replace the original `window.Websocket` class with a third-party one. To achieve that, I think I need to execute `window.Websocket = ThirdpartyWS` before every page is loaded.

I didn't read all the documents. I don't know how to execute an extension. I have thought about `background script`, and `content_scripts`, but none of them can satisfy me.

Comment: You need to run this code in [page context](/a/9517879) (use method 5). And specify "run_at": "document_start" for the content script.